# unexpected ACKing behavoir in GCM XMPP Protocol

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are using GCM’s XMPP protocol to deliver push notifications to our customers, the problem we are facing is that when sending xmpp messages with high speeds, we don’t receive 'ack' or 'nack' messages from GCM anymore, These are the results of several tests we did for this matter :

1. 500 XMPP messages - sent every 0.25 seconds:

   - all messages are acked
2. 500 XMPP messages - sent every 0.1 seconds:

   - On average, ~4 messages remained un-acked
3. 500 XMPP messages - sent every 0.01 seconds:

   - 72 messages remained un-acked
4. 500 XMPP messages - sent with no sleep time (As fast as possible)

   - reached the 100 unacked message limit set by GCM in less than 0.5 seconds !

The results are even worse when we go for more than 500 messages, E.g :

5. 4000 XMPP messages - sent every 0.1 seconds:

   - On average, number of un-acked messages rose to about 16
6. 4000 XMPP messages - sent every 0.01 seconds:

   - On average, reached the 100 unacked limit in the 800th xmpp message.

——————————————————————————————————

These results are from tests done on Google’s own cloud (Google cloud compute servers), while doing them in anyother place, would yield much worse results ( as we tested, no speed more than 1Msg/0.4S w 
We are using GCM’s XMPP protocol to deliver push nould actually survive (!) the 100 unacked limit)

This is too bad for us, since there’s no optimal solution out, what should we do now?

1. Ignore the 100 unacked limit and continue sending, but that would mean we don’t know whether our messages are received by gcm or not.
2. We can resend any unacked message after several seconds, but duplicate messages (to same clients) are a result.
3. Wait to see if they maybe get acked in the near future, but that so far hasn’t worked. When we get to the unacked limit, pending messages are never acked (in our experience)
4. Limit the speed by which we send XMPP messages, but this solution greatly jeopardizes the main initiative we had to actually use XMPP !

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are allowed to have more than one XMPP session open, so if you need to send more than one connection can handle, open 2 or 3 or 10

Comment: @e4c5 thanks, but if I have 10 open sockets, when an upstream message sent by one of the android clients, does Google send it to all of the 10 open sockets? it means 10x loads.

Comment: No google sends it to only one of the XMPP sessions so the other will not be burdened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem. I used to send ACKs for gcm's NACKs and when I stopped doing so, everything went perfectly fine. Check to see if you are sending unnecessary ACKs.

Comment: Wooooo, great. Google doesn't say anywhere "don't send ack for nack messages". Every thing is now working fine